# running a vc++ command line application on non development machine,

Tags: visual-c++

When I run command line application (executable generated using visual studio 2008) on non development windows 7 machine it gives following run time error "application has requested run time to terminate in unusual way. Please contact application support team for more information". It runs fine on a development machine.

Comment: Take a look: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884538/en-us

Answer (score 0):

With VS 2005 and VS 2008, Visual C++ used a side-by-side versioning scheme that requires manifest entries embeddded in the EXE to really work correctly in all cases. It's possible you are dealing with one of these. See these articles for details on debugging these side-by-side issues.

[Diagnosing SideBySide failures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/04/14/576314.aspx)

[Part 1: Troubleshooting VC++ Side by Side Problems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2008/08/07/part-1-troubleshooting-vc-side-by-side-problems.aspx)

[Part 2: Troubleshooting VC++ Side by Side Problems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2008/08/07/part-2-troubleshooting-vc-side-by-side-problems.aspx)

Note that with VS 2010 and later, Visual C++ no longer uses this side-by-side scheme. That said, there are still lots of reasons to use embedded manifests anyhow. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/10/manifest-madness.aspx) article.

Comment: Also note that between VS 2008 and VS 2008 SP1, there was a change in policy about which CRT version it tries to use by default. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/05/15/vc-runtime-binding.aspx) article. BTW, all the complexity around the CRT deployment is just another reason to upgrade to a newer VC++ :)